# Ruby moving directory error:

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I have a directory with many subdirectories and each of the subdirectories contains a different version of programme to test.

```
all_dirs.each do |dir|
  FileUtils.mv(test_spec, target_dir, :verbose => true)
  system("rspec #{test_folder_name}")
  puts "moving back: '#{spec_dir}' to '#{current_dir}'"
  FileUtils.mv(spec_dir, current_dir, :verbose => true)
end
```

In most cases the code is successful, however sometimes it refuses to move a directory to a parent directory, because it already exists.

```
mv ~/test/version-1/01-spec ~/test
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:509:in `block in mv': File exists - ~/test (Errno::EEXIST)
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1423:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1437:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1421:in `fu_each_src_dest'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:504:in `mv'
```

The unix `mv` command is valid and can be executed after this exception was thrown. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As the error tells you, it's failing because `~/test` already exists, and [FileUtils](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html) won't clobber it by default. You can pass the `force` parameter if you don't care about overwriting:

```
FileUtils.mv(test_spec, target_dir, :verbose => true, :force => true)
```

Comment: and why does it fail randomly? it can perform 5 iterations and then it fails on 6th one

Comment: @Tombart: from the file_utils source (https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/fileutils.rb#L583), you're probably seeing this when the destination entry is a directory. Which 5 does it succeed on specifically, and which 1 throws the error?

Comment: `:force` doesn't solve it, however when I run a `system("mv", spec_dir, current_dir)` it's ok. I'm running `ruby-1.9.3-p194`, so the code might be slightly different from the head version